# How to trim double quotes from string variable in postgreSQL function

Tags: sql, postgresql, plsql

I have a   function in postgreSQL,One of my function argument is   text type variable  and that   enclosed with in double   quotes   so i want to  insert this variable  to     table with out   double quotes ,when i search regarding this on net i got  a query like   `SELECT trim(both ' '  from  'techonthenet.com');`  but  this not working in the case of double quotes    so   how will i  remove   double quotes   from text string variable in postgreSQL function

Comment: @Kei when i SELECT trim(both '"' from "techonthenet.com");    try this   it seems error

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It is working:

```
postgres=# select '"Hello"';
┌──────────┐
│ ?column? │
╞══════════╡
│ "Hello"  │
└──────────┘
(1 row)

postgres=# select trim(both '"' from '"Hello"');
┌───────┐
│ btrim │
╞═══════╡
│ Hello │
└───────┘
(1 row)
```

Answer (score 2):

Another simple solution would be:

```
SELECT REPLACE('"Hello"', '"', '');
```

Answer (score 1):

SELECT TRIM('"Hello"', '"');

I used the above code to remove quotes from a column containing strings wrapped in double quotes:

SELECT  trim(lower(content_category), '"')
FROM Content;

Here I nested a function, lower, inside another function TRIM. IT WORKED FINE.