# How to replace double quotes to single quotes when use Sequelize to do raw query to Postgresql

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

I use Sequelize.js and follow this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55247612/postgresql-make-existing-primary-key-auto-incrementing-when-inserting) to update primary key value.
I run:

```js
await sequelize.query(`SELECT SETVAL('${idSeqence}', max(id)) FROM "${tableName}";`)
```

but error message says:

```
error: relation "my_bottemplates_id_seq" does not exist
sql: `SELECT SETVAL('my_botTemplates_id_seq', max(id)) FROM "myBotTemplates";
```

Then I follow this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58003722/how-to-trim-double-quotes-from-string-variable-in-postgresql-function) to try to replace double quotes
First try:

```js
await sequelize.query(`SELECT SETVAL(trim(both '"' from '"${idSeqence}"'), max(id)) FROM "${tableName}";`)
```

but I got the same error message again:

```
error: relation "my_bottemplates_id_seq" does not exist
sql: `SELECT SETVAL(trim(both '"' from '"my_botTemplates_id_seq"'), max(id)) FROM "myBotTemplates";`
```

Second try:

```js
await sequelize.query(`SELECT SETVAL(replace('${idSeqence}', ", '), max(id)) FROM "${tableName}";`)
```

This error message says:

```
error: syntax error at or near "myBotTemplates"
sql: `SELECT SETVAL(replace('my_botTemplates_id_seq', ", '), max(id)) FROM "myBotTemplates";`
```

Is there any method to run the SETVAL to update primary key value successfully?

Comment: You need to omit double quote, instead of `"${tableName}"`, try `${tableName}` that is without quote

Comment: @ArifKhan If I use `${tableName}`, error says: `error: relation "mybottemplates" does not exist`, but my table name is myBotTemplates

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the sequence contains upper case letters, it must be doublequoted in addition to the single quotes:

```sql
SELECT SETVAL('"my_botTemplates_id_seq"', max(id)) FROM "myBotTemplates";
```

or

```
await sequelize.query(`SELECT SETVAL('"${idSeqence}"', max(id)) FROM "${tableName}";`)
```